# ng-model won't reflect changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built a simple shopping cart sample  :

[image]

Those 3 lines are created via `ng-repeat`.

My goal :

I want the yellow part to become `red` when the relevant quantity ( red arrow) is `more than 3`.

So here is what I did : (http://jsbin.com/eXOgOpA/4/edit)

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <span ng-class='{isMoreThan3: IsMoreThan3()}'>{{item.title }}</span>
    <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
    ...
</div>
```

Where `IsMoreThan3` is a function which :

`$scope.IsMoreThan3=function (){return $scope.item.quantity>3;};`

Where

```
.isMoreThan3
{
  color:red;
}
```

but it doesn't work.*( calculations are ok  , but the color is never red).*

**Question :**

How can I fix my controller code to yield the right value for the model ?

**In other words :**

How can the controller  , know the current `item.quantity` ?

nb
I know that I can put the logic into the markup But I don't want that. I want the controller to return a `true/false` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<span ng-class='{isMoreThan3: IsMoreThan3(item)}'>{{item.title }}</span>
```

JS:

```
$scope.IsMoreThan3=function (item){
     return item.quantity>3;
};
```

The reason is `ng-repeat` will create **its own scope**, accessing `$scope.item` will not access the current item in the loop

Comment: ouch ... painfully simple , But why doesnt the controller know the    current item.quantity ? I mean : I did bound it to a model by ng-model....

Comment: @Royi Namir: `$scope` in your function is the controller's scope, not the scope created by `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Royi Namir: scopes in angular js inherit from its parent. In your case, the function is called with `the context of child scope` created by ng-repeat (this scope does not have `IsMoreThan3` function) . But because this scope inherits from parent scope (controller's scope) => it calls the parent's scope function. If you output `this` and `$scope` inside your function, you would see that they're not the same.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a way to get the current iteration  item scope ? ( I know that scopes are inherited)

Comment: @Royi Namir: if you don't want to pass variable into the function, you can access it by `return this.item.quantity>3;`. But this is not recommended as it **hardcodes** the `item` property (assumed in the html) and makes the code tightly coupled. Because if we have more nested child scopes inheriting this function, we may not use `item` in those child scopes but use another name (`it` for example) and the code will break

Comment: Couldn't ask for more...(p.s. I didnt know that each item creates its own scope)

Comment: P.s. - Assuming I have `this` , is there a property inside `this` which indicates the `$scope` ?  something like `this.parentScope` ?

Comment: @Royi Namir: yes, there is `this.$parent`